# How to avoid Checkbox CheckedChanged event firing at ListView creation time?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a simple XAML ListView including CheckBox (this a simple ToDo check list functionality).

The list displays fine, but the CheckBox CheckedChanged event fires when the list is first displayed. Which I guess is accurate since the CheckBox IsChecked value is set by the data binding, but this is not expected/intended.

Is this correct behaviour from the code?

What can I do to prevent this from happening? Also, if/when I do a list refresh.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTapped="OnEditStory" SeparatorVisibility="None"> 
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                            TextColor="#f35e20" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Number}"                             
                            TextColor="#503026" />
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsClosed}" CheckedChanged="OnCheckBoxCheckedChanged" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I expect that the CheckedChange event only fires when I/the user actually changes the value in the GUI i.e., checks or un-checks the CheckBox.

Comment: You can define a bool property (such as isFirstLoad) ,And set it to false when you check or uncheck the element .if(!isFirstLoad){ // do something you want }

Comment: Yes, that is an option. And maybe I can use the same when I perform a reload of the list. The list is fetched from a REST service and thus needs frequent updates/refreshes. But, I still think it could/should be handled differently...

Comment: I think it is the best way .Or you can handle it in `ViewModel` ,but you still need to check if it is the first time to load.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to `CheckedChanged` event after [Renderer](https://www.ston.is/xamarin-forms-secrets-renderer-property/) property has been set.

I'm doing MVVM, so here is my working approach:

- Create a [custom behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/creating) for `CheckBox`
- In the behavior: Subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event
- Subscribe to `CheckedChanged` when `Renderer` property has been changed:

  ```
  private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.PropertyName.Equals("Renderer", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
          AssociatedObject.CheckedChanged -= OnCheckedChanged;
          AssociatedObject.CheckedChanged += OnCheckedChanged;
      }
  }
  ```
- Attach the behavior to your checkbox control

P.S.: You need to use `CachingStrategy="RetainElement"` for the listview, so `CheckedChanged` event won't be triggered during scrolling.